# Factorial scaling on laptop makes external display a bit blurry

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, gnome, multiple-monitors, display

I have ASUS ROG Zephyrus G14 laptop with Ubuntu 20.04, it has 2K screen so I set scaling to 150%, but when I connect my external Dell display without scaling its content is blurry.

When I switch "Factorial scaling" off Dell shows good and crisp picture.

It feels like "Factorial scaling" option is switched on for both screens and changes the way how things get rendered.

Is it possible to have "Factorial scaling" option only for one display?

Comment: screen resolution of builtin screen is 2560x1440, screen resolution of external screen is 2560x1440

Comment: I use ubuntu gnome 20.04, As I see switch "factorial scaling" is switched on/off for both displays, you cannot use it only for one

Comment: Thanks for clarifying about 2K! I made two screenshots "fractional scaling: on" and "fractional scaling: off". The "on" screenshot is 2 times bigger than with "off" and it looks crisp. Feels like the picture is rendered 2x bigger and then downscaled when presented on screen... Yes I use native resolutions on both screens.